# Multitouch events on Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events, multi-touch

I have a very simple app made with Cordova: it has only one page, that is nothing else that a single big canvas on with i draw things.

My problem is: I need to interact with the page like: for each finger I put on the screen, I need to draw an object, that follows the finger who generated it and then, when the finger is released, the object is deleted; that's my logic:

```
canvas.addEventListener("pointerdown", clickhandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerDown", clickhandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", clickhandler, false);

canvas.addEventListener("pointermove", clickhandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerMove", clickhandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", clickhandler, false);

canvas.addEventListener("pointerup", clickhandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener("MSPointerUp", clickhandler, false);
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", clickhandler, false);
```

And `clickhandler` is:

```
function clickhandler(e) {
    if (e.preventManipulation) e.preventManupulation();
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    if (e.type.match(/(down|start)$/i)) {
        points[e.pointerId] = new AnimatedCircle(e.pageX, e.pageY, 40, 1000);
    } else if (e.type.match(/(move)$/i)) {
        points[e.pointerId].x = e.pageX;
        points[e.pointerId].y = e.pageY;
    } else if (e.type.match(/(up|end)$/i)) {
        points.splice(e.pointerId, 1);
    }
}
```

Pretty clear until this point, the problem is that I can't get over that strange behaviour I have.

If I tap an object is created; if I hold that finger and drag through the screen the object won't move (yes, I repaint it correctly), but the entire page will, as I was scrolling it. So, when I release, the object won't be deleted (this only if I moved the finger).

After a few touches, nothing works anymore.

Comment: What about the events ? Are they fired well ?

Comment: Have you tried CSS `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: @e666 they are not

Comment: #daserge yes i did